# I need explain about initialized passing values to array as parameter

Tags: java, arrays, variables

When I am studying about hashcode in Java, I find in class Objects
static method name hash.
This method have an array of Object as parameter so we can pass different type of object to this method and return hashcode of compained of all objects. In
`java.util.Objects`
we can see :

```
public static int hash(Object[] os) {
        // compiled code 
}
```

and we can pass parameter like that

```
String name="test";
int y=55;
char c='A';
Objects.hash(name,y,c);
```

When I try to make a method which has an array of Object as parameter
and try pass values to this method like that

```
String name="majd";
int y=54;
TestClass.testMethod(name,y);
```

The JVM give me an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: *"the jvm give me an error"*  - What error did you get? Can you post the `TestClass.testMethod` method declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the method signature of [`Objects#hash`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-) looks like this:

```
public static int hash(Object... values)
```

The `...` signifies a variadic parameter, meaning that it can be called with as many arguments as one wants.

Your method parameter should be declared with `...` instead of `[]` (which signifies an array).

```
public static void testMethod(Object... objects){
    //do something
}
testMethod("abc", 123, new Object());//example usage
```

Comment: So how i can make method like that and passing arguments

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way. Instead of using [] (array) you should go for ... (variable arguments). Varargs can take number of values.

```
public class Sample {

public static int testMethod(Object... os) {
    //your code here
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    String name="majd";
    int y=54;
    Objects.hash(name,y);
    Sample.testMethod(name,y);
}
```

}

Comment: Rather than post a code-dump answer, try to add some text to your answer, a paragraph or two, that explains why you are suggesting the code that you're posting and how your suggested changes will solve the original poster's problems. Without this, your answer will not likely help future visitors.